# How to add comments to a Jena model?

Tags: rdf, jena

I have created a model with the Jena API.

```
private Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
```

Now I want to add comments, like when created. These should apprear in the ttl file when I save it.

Searching Google for keywork like "comment" doesnt help much (which is why I am developing ontology in the first place!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I want to add comments, like when created. These should apprear in
>   the ttl file when I save it.

I don't *think* that there's any provision for doing that.  RDF, as a data model, doesn't have any concept of comments (even though some serialization formats, like Turtle and RDF/XML allow comments), and so in general there'd be no way to preserve comments between serializations (since you might write to a file format that doesn't support comments at all).  It would be very hard to specify where comments should appear, too, since the order of triples doesn't exist in RDF, so there needn't be any guarantees about where things appear in a file.

You could, of course, add triples using a "comment" predicate, like **rdfs:comment**, in which case the comments are *part* of the data, and would be preserved.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, that makes sense and does help. Maybe I will create a wrapper which holds the model and my meta data.